# Strange behaviour with UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I'm seeing some strange behaviour with my UItableViewController shown using Popover.

This is my ViewController code:

```
@interface PrepareViewController ()
{
NSMutableArray *_objects;
NSString *savingKey;
}

@end

@implementation PrepareViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
[super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

// Register a class or nib file using registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier
// o registerClass:forCellReuiseIdentifier: method before calling this method
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

// Setup savingKey
savingKey = @"prepareKey";

// Load the items from NSUserDefaults
_objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:savingKey]];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)defaultsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
// Setup savingKey
savingKey = @"prepareKey";

// Load the items from NSUserDefaults
_objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:savingKey]];

// Reload the tableView
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)dealloc {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)saveSummaries {
// Save the summaries to NSUserDefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_objects forKey:savingKey];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return _objects.count;
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Open the chosen item
MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
sharedManager.openSummary = _objects[indexPath.row];

// Modal to SummaryViewController
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"summarySegue" sender:self];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    // Delete the associated information
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", _objects[indexPath.row], @"-summary"]];

    NSLog(@"delete3");

    // Save the new list of combined summaries
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_objects forKey:@"prepareKey"];
} else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
}
}

@end
```

**Problem:**
When the user taps delete while in edit mode, no animation appears and the selected item snaps back into place without any animation and the item remains undeleted. I've checked that the delete method gets called - any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of this:

```
- (void)defaultsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
// Setup savingKey
savingKey = @"prepareKey";

// Load the items from NSUserDefaults
_objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:savingKey]];

// Reload the tableView
[self.tableView reloadData]; <------- manual reload without animations
}
```

When you change defaults in:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

that code is executed.

Comment: Oh I see! Could I solve this by simply creating a BOOL for when I want the defaultsChanged to ignore the notification?

Comment: You can solve it this way, or I think better is to not do it through automatic notification, just call this on purpose when you need directly - I mean refreshing dataSource and reloading table. If you ever change a data source to be database or loaded from web - it's easier to replace :)